# How do I install a progressive web app if I don't see the icon in the url?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, gmail, google-calendar-api, progressive-web-apps

So Gmail and Gcalendar should theoretically have one the "Install" icon at the URL to install as a progressive web app... except I don't have it and cannot understand why. This is one of those questions that cannot be googled. I don't know where else to turn to.